# apache2 www permission for PHP

Tags: php, permissions, apache2, debian

I've installed a new debian 6.0 x64 server with apache2 and php5. I need function like "parse_ini_file", "mkdir", etc. but somehow the permission isn't right for my /var/www folder. Any tips how to set the permission for the /var/www folder?

This is my current permission for the /var/www folder:

```
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root  4096 Mar  4 17:12 www
```

Comment: owned by `www-data:www-data` (or whatever user apache runs as in debian), permission `0755`

Comment: `chown –R www-data:www /var/www` and `chmod -R 755 /var/www` This is what i added.

Comment: yes, thanks. see my comment above. i've used the wrong group. www-data instead of www.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change your owner or rights to respond user, you are logged on. For example, `root` can change `john's` files, but `john`, user hierarchically under the `root`, **can't** change his files.

- Change owner of folder/file

  chown user:group /var/www
- Change rights of folder/file

  chmod [xxx] /var/www

*You can also add -R argument to execute command recursively, it's standing directly after `chown` and `chmod`.

**[xxx] usualy used 755, but be carefull about this!

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod

http://linuxcommand.org/lts0070.php

Comment: This is what i added: `chown –R www-data:www /var/www` and `chmod -R 755 /var/www` I can't still use my parse_ini_file file. I have a script which reads the config data from a ini file, but i don't get them(just empty results).

Comment: Try to check everything again and restart the server. Is your user and group setted up properly?

Comment: Still not working. Look, i've installed debian for first time on my own. I just used the simple installation without a graphical interface. This commands i execute after the installation: `aptitude install apache2,
aptitude install php5 libapache2-mod-php5,
apt-get install php5-ldap,
groupadd www,
gpasswd –a www-data www,
chown –R www-data:www /var/www
` Nothing more

Comment: it's `chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www` note the missing `-data` part in what you've already tried

Comment: Yes, you were doing everything fine, but I've absolutely overlooked what @Crisp reminded. He is right with www-data:www-data, use it.